# Evento en Javascript no funciona al hacer click y querer llenar una tabla capturando los valores de un select

Tags: javascript, while, function, html-select, calculo

En este código se desea llenar una tabla capturando los valores de un select escuchado el click del botón "Calcular".

Justamente hay una función para calcular la cuota mediante los valores "monto", "interés" y "tiempo" pero al disparar el evento aparece por consola el mensaje de "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'firstChild')" y cuando voy al error es en la línea del ciclo while donde no puede leer ese valor que le estoy pasando al ciclo.

Intenté de varias formas, haciendo cambios y reformulando y nada, no puedo calcular capturando esos valores. Quizás haya que plantearlo de alguna otra forma que en el momento no se me ocurre.

Nota: Se está trabajando con la librería Moment.js por CDN y en alguna línea debajo del ciclo se declara la fecha actual con Date.now

```js
class Habitacion {
  constructor(tipo, cantidad, precio, maximoPersonas) {
    this.tipo = tipo;
    this.cantidad = cantidad;
    this.precio = precio;
    this.maximoPersonas = maximoPersonas;
    this.disponibilidad = true;
  }
  sumaIva() {
    this.precio = this.precio * 1.21;
  }
  vender() {
    if (this.cantidad <= 0) {
      this.disponibilidad = false;
    } else {
      this.cantidad = this.cantidad - 1;
    }
  }
}

const habitacionTipo1 = new Habitacion("Tipo1", 50, 6200, 2);

const habitacionTipo2 = new Habitacion("Tipo2", 40, 6500, 2);

const habitacionTipo3 = new Habitacion("Tipo3", 5, 7500, 3);

// ---------- suma del IVA ----------
habitacionTipo1.sumaIva();
habitacionTipo2.sumaIva();
habitacionTipo3.sumaIva();

// Evento //

const monto = document.getElementById("monto");
const tiempo = document.getElementById("tiempo");
const interes = document.getElementById("interes");
const btnCalcular = document.getElementById("btnCalcular");
const llenarTabla = document.querySelector("#lista-tabla tbody");

btnCalcular.addEventListener("click", () => {
  calcularCuota(monto.value, interes.value, tiempo.value);
})

function calcularCuota(monto, interes, tiempo) {
  while (llenarTabla.firstChild) {
    llenarTabla.removeChild(llenarTabla.firstChild);
  } // acá no funciona
  let fechas = [];
  let fechaActual = Date.now();
  let mes_actual = moment(fechaActual);
  mes_actual.add(1, "month");

  let pagoInteres = 0,
    pagoCapital = 0,
    cuota = 0;

  cuota = monto * (Math.pow(1 + interes / 100, tiempo) * interes / 100) / (Math.pow(1 + interes / 100, tiempo) - 1);

  for (let i = 1; i <= tiempo; i++) {
    pagoInteres = parseFloat(monto * (interes / 100));
    pagoCapital = cuota - pagoInteres;
    monto = parseFloat(monto - pagoCapital);

    //Formato de las fechas
    fechas[i] = mes_actual.format("DD-MM-YYYY");
    mes_actual.add(1, "month");

    const row = document.createElement("tr");
    row.innerHTML = `
                <td>${fechas[i]}</td>
                <td>${cuota.toFixed(2)}</td>
                <td>${pagoCapital.toFixed(2)}</td>
                <td>${pagoInteres.toFixed(2)}</td>
                <td>${monto.toFixed(2)}</td>
                `;
    llenarTabla.appendChild(row) // debería funcionar y nada
  }
  console.log(cuota);
}
```

```html
<!-- Link de bootstrap -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="gridContainer">
  <header>

  </header>
  <main class="main">
    <h3>Reservas</h3>
    <div>
      <select id="list">
        <option value="1000">Tipo1</option>
        <option value="1500">Tipo2</option>
        <option value="2500">Tipo3</option>
        <option value="3000">Tipo4</option>
      </select>
      <br>
      <br>
      <input type="number" name="currency-field" id="monto" data-type="Monto" placeholder="$1,000,000" autocomplete="off " min="0">
      <br>
      <br>
      <input type="number" name="currency-field" id="tiempo" placeholder="Meses" autocomplete="off " min="0">
      <br>
      <br>
      <input type="number" name="currency-field" id="interes" placeholder="Interes" autocomplete="off " min="0">
      <br>
      <br>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnCalcular">Calcular</button>
      <table id="lista-tabla" class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Fecha</th>
            <th>Cuota</th>
            <th>Capital</th>
            <th>Interés</th>
            <th>Saldo</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
      </table>
    </div>
  </main>
  <footer>
    <div>
      <p>Prueba</p>
    </div>
  </footer>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.3/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

Comment: A tu `table` le falta el `tbody`, por esto, la variable `llenarTabla` es null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El tema es... ¿dónde tienes ese código?
Por estás definiendo las constantes monto, tiempo, interes... sobre `document.getElementById`y quizá en el momento de declararlas no existen todavía.

Si pones estas declaraciones (y funciones posteriores) después del Load, ya sería otra cosa. Al menos el de `const btnCalcular`

De todos modos, monto, tiempo e interés los declararía dentro del `addEventListener`, que es el único sitio donde lo utilizas, y `llenarTabla` dentro de `function calcularCuota`, y así el único tema a tener en cuenta es declarar `const btnCalcular` en un lugar adecuado, para cuando ya la página se haya generado.